# apt broken in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, apt

I'm tying to install `python-pip` package. But `sudo apt install python-pip` gives me the following error:

```
$ sudo apt install python-pip     
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apport-symptoms python3-systemd
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  python-setuptools python-wheel
Suggested packages:
  python-setuptools-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python-pip python-setuptools python-wheel
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 361 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,376 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 python-pip all 8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4 [144 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 python-setuptools all 20.7.0-1 [169 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 python-wheel all 0.29.0-1 [48.0 kB]
Fetched 361 kB in 1s (242 kB/s)        
Selecting previously unselected package python-pip.
(Reading database ... 402905 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python-pip_8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-pip (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-setuptools.
Preparing to unpack .../python-setuptools_20.7.0-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-setuptools (20.7.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-wheel.
Preparing to unpack .../python-wheel_0.29.0-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-wheel (0.29.0-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up python-pip (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-pip (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-setuptools (20.7.0-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-setuptools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-wheel (0.29.0-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-wheel (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-pip
 python-setuptools
 python-wheel
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I also tried to install `python-apt` but it gives me same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
```

The module "ConfigParser" seems to be missing ... I found this, hope it helps :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087598/python-3-importerror-no-module-named-configparser#23978968

You can use `help('modules')` in a python 3 command shell to find the right spelling for that module.

If you can't find it using the above command, I guess that you'll need to reinstall apt from the LiveCD.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your default python version is 3.X. I solved this problem with install python3-pip instead of python-pip.

When using pip please differ pip for python2 and pip3 for python3.